# How to tell python app I am returning JSON

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7, shopify

I have a shopify app I use to sync quantities between shopify and our POS systems. Recently it started throwing a "406 not acceptable" error. I have tracked it down (i think) to when I make the actual call to update the quantity, this line:

```
return shopify.Variant(dict(id=288275460, inventory_quantity=3.0)).save()
```

I have hard-coded values that should work but the moment it tries to execute this command i get the traceback posted below.

From what I think is happening is that shopify stopped returning XML and now the returned data isn't acceptable to the python application on my webhost that is executing these commands. What I don't understand is how I would specify that my application should expect the proper content-type. Currently I am not even processing the returned data in any way just executing the command without even a return causes the same error. Just really confused which is unfortunately rather easy.

TRACEBACK:

```
Internal Server Error: /inventory/process/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/crabs/.virtualenvs/webhostname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/crabs/.virtualenvs/webhostname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crabs/projects/webfaction/webdomain.com/apps/shopified/views.py", line 115, in process
    dictUpdated = update(sku, arraydata[0], arraydata[1])
  File "/home/crabs/projects/webfaction/webdomain.com/apps/shopified/inventory.py", line 72, in update
    return simplejson.dumps(shopify.Variant(dict(id=288275460, inventory_quantity=3.0)).save())
  File "/home/crabs/.virtualenvs/webhostname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 775, in save
    data=self.to_xml())
  File "/home/crabs/.virtualenvs/webhostname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 351, in put
    return self._open('PUT', path, headers=headers, data=data)
  File "/home/crabs/.virtualenvs/webhostname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shopify/base.py", line 19, in _open
    self.response = super(ShopifyConnection, self)._open(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crabs/.virtualenvs/webhostname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 287, in _open
    http_response = self._handle_error(err)
  File "/home/crabs/.virtualenvs/webhostname/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 415, in _handle_error
    raise ClientError(err)
ClientError: Response(code=406, body=" ", headers={'status': '406 Not Acceptable', 'x-request-id': '6be354d6-686b-4146-bcf3-03ed080756a2', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-shopify-asset-version': '1', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'x-shardid': '0', 'x-stats-apiclientid': '149305', 'connection': 'close', 'server': 'nginx', 'x-stats-apipermissionid': '2992571', 'x-shopid': '2117110', 'x-stats-userid': '0', 'x-ua-compatible': 'chrome=1', 'http_x_shopify_shop_api_call_limit': '1/40', 'date': 'Wed, 16 Jul 2014 19:06:48 GMT', 'x-shopify-shop-api-call-limit': '1/40', 'content-type': 'application/xml'}, msg="Not Acceptable")
```

Comment: use `import json; json.dumps(dict(id=288275460, inventory_quantity=3.0))`

Comment: Try updating the version of the shopified app you have on your server (and it's dependencies) first.  Poking around the various packages you're routing through, it looks like you're on a fairly old version of things.  It looks like there should be a configuration somewhere in your shopified app, or where you are setting up shopify/pyactiveresource where you can set the message format.  Try to track that down (after grabbing the latest version,as it looks like the older version you are on may not have even supported JSON).

Comment: Thanks for the info this sounds highly likely to me. I will investigate and report back!

Comment: This did the trick on my dev machine, testing live now.Thanks! How do i mark your reply as an answer?